# MSXML 6 installation prerequisites

Tags: msxml, msxml6, msxml2, msxml3, msxml4

Good Day!

Currently on one of our servers MSXML 4 is installed which is an obsolete version.
Now we want to upgrade it to MSXML 6.0 SP2.

However I could not get link from where I could install MSXML6_x64.msi installer

I tried downloading it from
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-an-update-for-msxml-core-services-6-0-service-pack-2-9b310b5a-3a90-ebc3-e1bd-97b42266b1ef
but got some exe downloaded rather than msi installer and it did not run even with administrator privileges & gave error installation interrupted.

1. Could you suggest from where I could download MSXML 6.0 latest installer.
2. Could you confirm if the upgrade steps are correct as following

> ```
> a) verify in "Program and Features" that MSXML < version 6 is installed
> b) use the "uninstall" option to remove MSXML < version 6
> c) download latest version
> d) run the MSI installation and follow Instructions
> ```

In case I've missed anything please confirm.

Thanks